# Handling local files and folders in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, local-storage

Does anyone know how to, or if it's even possible, to copy files and/or folder structures to the local storage of an app using React Native? I am looking to use raster tiles for mapping and I want to package them with the app and then copy them to local for use. This is something I am really struggling to find any answers to out there. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague in what you are trying to do. If you mean you need to bundle the images and have them be available from within your app, even offline, then you simply need to put them in your app's source tree and require them. If you need to handle dynamic image names then you could export an object keyed to the image names and require them all in object so you could then select an image based on a variable/key.

```
const images = {
  map2x2: require('../images/2x2.png'),
  map2x3: require('../images/2x3.png'),
  map2x4: require('../images/2x4.png'),
};

const pieceKey = 'map2x2';

<Image source={images[pieceKey]} />
```

The packager will bundle them with your app and even handles selecting proper resolution if the images have multiple sizes (@2x, @3x)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Now if you are asking to download remote images from a webserver and save them locally to be used within your app then you will probably find a package to help with that.